# How to only give the address in the HTTP Request Connector?

Tags: java, http, mule

In Mule 3.6, the new HTTP Request Connector requires a host and a port number in its config. I have only the address like `www.google.com`. I do not the port number. How do I enter only the address?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question about address only in HTTP Request Connector, but a HTTP call **requires** a port, the standard port for web pages is 80 (or 443 if HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

Hi in **http connector properties** in the left side you can see **Advanced** tab in that you can see **Address** text box give your address in that.

Answer (score 0):

in advance tab of http request connector there are attributes like host and port.
in the host you can provide domain address and port of domain address for www.google.com port will be 80 i guess.

below is the syantax

`<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" host="www.google.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP"/>`

try and let me know the status, it worked for me.

Comment: I am not going to use google. That was just an example. I tried 8080 but it didn't work.